# Add click event to map marker infowindow

Tags: javascript

I want to add a click event to this function so when the map marker is clicked on data in the practice is displayed in a list. Currently, this function runs on load.

```
   function resultsList(){
var list = document.querySelector('#resultlist');
list.innerHTML = '<ul>' + practice.map(function (practice) {
    return '<li>' + practice.name + practice.address; '</li>';
}).join('') + '</ul>';

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think you mean is following code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
  resultsList();
});
```

for more detail read this tutorial [google_maps_events](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_events.asp)

Comment: you are right but my next problem is that I am pretty new to JavaScript and I dont know were to this now.

Comment: @Lisa123456 add a link of google map events tutorial